# Python Selenium WebDriverWait not working, driver.findElement working

Tags: python, selenium, radio-button, webdriverwait

I'm trying to enable a RadioButton with Selenium.

I’m getting buttons and textfields and all that stuff with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr..'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

but now when it comes to the radio Button it suddenly fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jan/PycharmProjects/MailCreation/mail_creation", line 53, in <module>
    creator.create(1)
  File "/home/jan/PycharmProjects/MailCreation/mail_creation", line 43, in create
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'id-signup-radio-email'))).click()
  File "/home/jan/PycharmProjects/MailCreation/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

First I thought maybe its because of a iframe, but I cant find one.

I tried it several times with id, css-selector and xpath with that line of code:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'id-signup-radio-email'))).click()
```

it fails, every single time.
then I tried

```
time.sleep(3)
test = driver.find_element_by_id('id-signup-radio-email')
test.click()
```

and it somehow works perfectly fine.
WHY? I don’t get it. So it really isn’t about getting it to work, but about understanding why.

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm trying to enable a RadioButton with Selenium."

Disabled elements are not clickable. Try `EC.presence_of_element_located` instead of `EC.element_to_be_clickable`.

So basically:

```
target element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id-signup-radio-email')))
```